# "leave many [N] to look for…" vs. "leave many [N] looking for…"

Tags: word-choice, infinitive-vs-gerund

SAT Grammar Question

> Others, like court interpreter Ludmila Baker, believe that technology will ultimately leave many translators and interpreters _______ for new careers.
>
> a) to look
>   b) looking

Which of the two is grammatically correct and why?

Comment: What do you think??  (And why?)

Comment: Well, I'm not very sure. The answer is "looking," but I feel like "to look" could also work.

Comment: Tricky question! Not easy at all.

Comment: 'Leave many' will more naturally take 'looking'. But 'prompt many' would more naturally take 'to look'. There is more here than appears at first glance.

Comment: Once again, it's the verbs. _Leave_ takes a gerund in _leave `X V`-ing_, not an infinitive; but _prompt_ takes an infinitive with _to_ in  _prompt `X` to `V`_. And _help_ can have either a gerund or an infinitive (with or without _to_, even) in _help `X V`/help `X V`-ing/help `X to V`_.

Comment: 'Leave' can take a DO plus to-infinitival, but the sense changes. 'We were in a hurry, so we left them to look for the missing papers.' (ie we didn't help). This sense is not available in OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you were to say that 'technology will ultimately leave many translators and interpreters to look for new careers' it implies that technology is leaving. However, if you use looking, it implies that it is the translators and interpreters that are looking.